# Why are the distances in real space and Fourier space inverses of each other?

Tags: cosmology, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, dimensional-analysis

I just came across a paragraph in a set of physics notes where they implicitly claim that imposing a cut-off $k<\Lambda$ to the modes in Fourier space is equivalent to smoothing the field in real space at a scale $R=1/\Lambda$.

Can anyone give me any tips to prove this or just to understand it better? I keep hearing in the context of Cosmology that large scales in distance mean small Fourier modes and viceversa, but I need to understand why. It must be something very elementary that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible answers to this question. The duality (large wavenumber = small lengthscales) is very deeply rooted in the Fourier analysis with many applications, see for example Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

You are interested in understanding why a cutoff in frequency corresponds to a smoothing in real space. One can understand this quite directly by introducing a cutoff function $0\leq G(k)\leq 1$ with the properties $G(k\ll \Lambda) =1$ and $G(k \gg \Lambda)=0$. You might take a box-function, a Fermi-function. For concreteness, the simplest is the Gaussian
$$ G(k) = e^{-(k/\Lambda)^2}\,.$$

Having an arbitrary function $f(x)$ with the Fourier-transform
$$ F(k) = \int e^{-i kx}f(x) dx;$$
the cutoff is implemented by the replacement
$$ F(k) \mapsto \tilde F(k) = F(k) G(k)\,.$$
In real space, this corresponds to (using the convolution theorem)
$$ \tilde f(x) = \int\!dx' f(x-x') g(x'),$$
i.e., the values of the function $f$ are smeared out over the support given by
$$g(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int e^{i kx}G(k) dk\,.$$
For the example of the Gaussian, we have
$$ g(x) = \frac{\Lambda}{2\sqrt{\pi}} e^{- \Lambda^2 x^2/4}\,.$$
Thus, $\tilde f$ is smeared out version of $f$ over a lengthscale $\sim 2/\Lambda$.